# How to deploy web apps to Azure using Release mode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, deployment

I am trying to deploy a ASP.NET website to Microsoft Azure from Visual Studio, While Deploying to Azure It does not list release mode under setting.

How I can get listed release mode under setting.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are publishing a website(**File**->**New Web Site** option in VS) rather than a web application(**File**->**New Project**->**Web Application**), then this is by design. There is no release option for publishing website in Visual Studio. For publishing a website, you don't really need a Release mode as when it is built all of the files within it will be copied to the appropriate location. Check [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/2033338.aspx?Visual%20Studio%202013%20web%20express%20Publish%20asp%20net%204%200%20website%20under%20release%20mode) for details.

If you want to publish the web site in release mode, please create your web site via **File->New Project->Web Application**. Hope this helps.